# How to prevent particular migration execution in code first Entity Framework?

Tags: sql, oracle, entity-framework, migration, ef-code-first

I am using code first with `Entity Framework 6` in `Windows Form Application` with `Code based migration`.
Code based migration i added only form Oracle because Oracle DB not allow to use dynamic schema name with code first.So, i added dynamically through code based migration.

I have multiple database connection (Dynamically end user can connect any SQLDB and OracleDB).So, I found some migration related issues when connection will switch from Oracle to SQL. I want to set migration execution based on some specific condition only (Not always need to execute migration when connect with new or existing Oracle DB). I am still not sure this type of way possible or not. Because i want to prevent unwanted DB change through migration. Or i am looking for some better solutions. Because Oracle dynamic schema name migration affect on SQL connection when application will run.

**What i tried from my side**
Set some migration code in Migration class UP method conditionally. But it's not helpful because it is always create or apply some empty or null migration. Also, generate table => `MigrationHistory`.

In my scenario i want to completely prevent migration execution when connection done with SQL. In application execution splash screen offer Database selection Oracle or SQL so based on that selection i want to set code based migration execution. If SQL then not need to execute code based migration . Only required to execute when Oracle connection.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks!